# How to get objects from AWS S3 with incomplete key with Ruby app

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm  trying to get objects from AWS S3 with a certain words in a Ruby app. There are many files having "lesson_id_" as a part of key, and I would love to download all files including this key word. But if I search with 'lesson_id_*' it says, AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key.

I want to efficiently download all files including this key word. Please give me any feedback how to use "keywords" instead of perfect "key".

```
obj = S3_BUCKET.objects['lesson_id_*']

begin

File.open("name", 'wb') do |file|
obj.read do |chunk|
file.write(chunk)
end
end

rescue
end
```

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/ObjectCollection.html suggests you are looking for  something that looks like `bucket.objects.with_prefix('lesson_id_')` ... You don't want the `*`, for sure -- you're specifying a string prefix, no wildcard support.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Get all the objects and check them before you download them. You can then use a regex or whatever you like to check the

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')

bucket = s3.bucket('your-bucket')

bucket.objects.limit(1000).each do |item|
    if item.key.start_with?('lesson_id_') 
        obj = bucket.object(item.key)
        obj.get(response_target: item.key)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the full key by using the following method

```
resp = api_client.list_objects({ bucket: <bucket-name>, prefix: 'your-prefix-'})
```

then get the exact file by using the `.get_object` method.

```
file_path = resp.contents[0].key
s3_response = api_client.get_object({ bucket: <bucket-name>, key: file_path })
```